# Can I grab shipping cost in Amazon Web Services API using PHP?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services

I want to know if it is possible to get shipping cost AWS, I cannot find any or am I just missing something? In my responsegroup I use Large as of the moment

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=27214

Maybe it is not possible using AWS, the suggestions on the linked thread are to do with accessing the actual web page for the article.